# How to replace each string in a list with some other string in python

Tags: python, list, replace

I'm making a hangman game, recently started python and looks like a good project I'd like to do, and so far its going great, I have a function that takes a string and puts it in a list like this:

```
Word: duck
List: ["d", "u", "c", "k"]
```

Now I want to replace the D U C K letters with "_"
I tried:

```
for char in List:
   List.replace("d", "_")
```

This doesn't do anything also I dont want to do it for every single letter separately I would like something like this:

```
for char in List:
   List.replace(char, "_")
```

I hope this is understandable

Comment: `List = ["_" for character in List]`

Comment: Also, lists don't have a `.replace()` method, so I don't see how your code could have run.

Comment: @JohnGordon That will replace everything by `_`

Comment: @Tarik The questioner said: Now I want to replace the D U C K letters with "_"

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in two steps:

```
# Find the index of the string in your list
index = List.index(char)

# Replace
List[index] = '_'
```

The code above would replace the first occurrence only. To replace all you can either loop while the index is not -1 or use a comprehension:

```
List = ['_' if c == char else c for c in List]
```

or if you want to replace a specified set of letters:

```
chars = ['D', 'U', 'C', 'K']
List = ['_' if c in chars else c for c in List]
```

If all you want is a series of `_` characters, then you might as well use this:

```
List = ['_'] * len(List)
```